# Url rewriting and folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have my website with a sub-directory:

```
http://www.mysite.com/test/
```

Inside "test" directory I have:

```
index.php
included-inside-index-file.php
another-included-inside-index-file.php
script.php
```

Now, how can i rewrite url with .htaccess so it works like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/test --> access index.php
http://www.mysite.com/test/beautiful-url --> access script.php?parameter=beautiful-url
http://www.mysite.com/test/included-inside-index-file.php --> 404 error
http://www.mysite.com/test/another-included-inside-index-file.php --> 404 error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward.  You need a generic rule for the `beautiful-url`, but preceded by rules which throw `[R=404,L]` for the scripts you want to hide.

```
RewriteEngine On

# First hide the includes
# These could be simplified if they follow a pattern.
# Here we'll list them individually though.
RewriteRule ^test/included-inside-index-file\.php - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^test/another-included-inside-index-file\.php - [R=404,L]

# Then rewrite to the beautiful URL if the file doesn't exist.
# The index.php will serve normally because it does exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^test/(.+)$ test/script.php?parameter=$1 [L]
```

If you want to explicitly block direct access to `script.php`, you can match it inside `THE_REQUEST`. Place this after the rules which block access to the includes. I *think* this will work.  If you tried to do it without the `RewriteCond`, you would get 404's from the beautiful url rewrites.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} script\.php
RewriteRule ^. - [R=404,L]
```

Comment: thank you! this should work! as soon as i test it i'll mark your answer correct.